ITMS-91064 NSPrivacyTracking must be true if NSPrivacyTrackingDomains isn‘t empty. Keys and values
I have issue releasing a react-native project in appStore after I submit the app. I get rejection from Apple
rejection msg:

ITMS-91064: Invalid tracking information - A PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
file contains invalid tracking information at the following path:
“Frameworks/SASDisplayKit.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy”.
NSPrivacyTracking must be true if NSPrivacyTrackingDomains isn‘t
empty. Keys and values in your app’s privacy manifest must be valid.
For more details about privacy manifest files

I added this snippet from react-native to my project in the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
    <array/>
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array/>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>C617.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>35F9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


Note: I also update react-native-firebase/analytics to the latest version 19.2.2, because according to the issue in GitHub I need to update to the latest version, however that didn't fix it
this how the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy looks from Xcode

any clue how to fix this issue?

It seems that the problem lies with the SASDisplayKit framework's privacy file. You could check with their support

As Apple wrote:

A PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file contains invalid tracking information at the following path: “Frameworks/SASDisplayKit.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy”.
NSPrivacyTracking must be true if NSPrivacyTrackingDomains isn‘t empty.

you should identify the location of the file:
Frameworks/SASDisplayKit.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

and make sure it has the key-value:
<key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
<true/>


For example,

open Terminal application of Mac.

go to the root directory of your app's project:
% cd ...


list all the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files of your app:
% find . -name PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy


identify the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy of SASDisplayKit

open it and make sure the key-value:
% open ...




In Release notes of Smart-Display-SDK:

Version 7.23.4
April 30th, 2024
iOS 13.0+

[Fixed] Display SDK privacy manifest, this will prevent your app from being rejected by Apple validation process.


Since this is SASDisplayKit according to its Podspec:
"vendored_frameworks": "SASDisplayKit.xcframework"

you can avoid rejection with this latest version.

@qtmfld my app is using capacitor,i have created PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file using ionic vscode extension.NSPrivacyTracking is set to false now, should i change to true.i have not submitted my updated app to testfliht
